# setup logger in init and use in python files in the same folder

Tags: python, logging

Anybody can explain what i am doing wrong in here?

I got below code:

```
# my_code.py
import logging
loger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
loger.info("Hello logging!")
```

and in the second file:

```
# __init__.py
import logging.config

# Create the Logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create the Handler for logging data to a file
logger_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='test.txt')
logger_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create a Formatter for formatting the log messages
logger_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Add the Formatter to the Handler
logger_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)

# Add the Handler to the Logger
logger.addHandler(logger_handler)
logger.info('Completed configuring logger()!')
```

So based on what i was thinking is written on logging tutorial
I would get a logs from file my_code in the file test.txt but for some reason i am not getting it.
Would somebody explain me what do i have to change in **init** so it changes settings of logger for the file my_code too please?

my file setup.py

```
    from setuptools import find_packages, setup
    
    setup(
        name='my_folder1',
        packages=find_packages(),
        version='0.1.0',
        description='',
        author='',
        license='',
    )
```

I also tried to do:
pip install .

```
setup.py  
my_folder1  
--my_folder2:  
----init.py  
----my_code.py 
----some_diff_file.py
```

I am using Python 3.6.11

Thank you

Comment: `__name__` is differend in both files. Replace it by `"my-logger"`, for example.

Comment: @WolfgangKuehn i changed it to the same name and it still doesn't work